# how to mutate state in react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, mern

i am using createSlice way to implement redux for the first time and i am trying to mutate state in the store which is not working and the object that i am updating is getting undefined.
please help me fix it

```
[save.fulfilled]:(state,action)=>{
      console.log("inside save it");
      console.log(action.payload,"test");
      console.log(current(state));
      current(state).list.map((C,i)=>{
        console.log(C._id,"ii");
        if(C._id==action.payload._id){
          const temp=Object.assign({},C);
          temp=action.payload.obj
          return temp;
        }
        return C;
      })
      console.log(current(state).list);
    }
```

if id matches i need to mutate a key

```
Object { form: {…}, _id: "617ce521028ba1920422fb6b" }
​
_id: "617ce521028ba1920422fb6b"
​
form: Object { name: "adarsh hh", email: "adarsh@gmail.com", phone: "8340484685", … }
​
```

above is the action object,below is the state

```
Object { list: (2) […], status: "succeeded" }
​
list: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { _id: "617ce521028ba1920422fb6b", userid: "616548965d47a2b6ec0a1592", key: 0, … }
​​​
__v: 0
​​​
_id: "617ce521028ba1920422fb6b"
​​​
created: "2021-10-30T06:24:33.922Z"
​​​
form: Object { name: "adarsh raii", email: "adarsh@gmail.com", phone: "8340484685", … }
​​​
key: 0
​​​
updated: "2021-10-30T06:24:33.922Z"
​​​
userid: "616548965d47a2b6ec0a1592"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
1: Object { _id: "617ce5a2028ba1920422fb72", userid: "616548965d47a2b6ec0a1592", key: 0, … }
​​​
__v: 0
​​​
_id: "617ce5a2028ba1920422fb72"
​​​
created: "2021-10-30T06:26:42.600Z"
​​​
form: Object { name: "adarsh raj", email: "adarsh@gmail.com", phone: "8340484685", … }
​​​
key: 0
​​​
updated: "2021-10-30T06:26:42.600Z"
​​​
userid: "616548965d47a2b6ec0a1592"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
length: 2
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
status: "succeeded"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

**i just want to mutate the form object of a particular field object by matching the _id so as to update it in dom**

Comment: can you show me whole reducer file

Comment: https://textdoc.co/Dol7z481GnAVOJeX here it is

Answer (score 0):

if cant mutate the redux state, you've to copy the state
you need to work on your logic.
i think below code would suffice your requirement let me know.

```
[save.fulfilled]:(state,action)=>{
      console.log("inside save it");
      console.log(action.payload,"test");
      console.log(current(state));
      let temp= Object.assign({},current(state));
      temp.list.forEach((C,i)=>{
        console.log(C._id,"ii");
        if(C._id==action.payload._id){
          temp.list[i] = action.payload.obj
        }
       
      })
    return temp; 
      console.log(current(state).list);
    }
```

Comment: okay got it ,should i go this way by using createSlice or other way in redux, what good projects can help me learn more?

Comment: There are lots of good tutorial available online, i reckon youre using redux toolkit package for starters i recommend to using redux without any third party middleware.  if the answer suffuce your doubts pls marked it as anwered